# Get all active alerts of a subscription in Azure Monitor using Python

Tags: python, azure

I just needed to get all active alerts from Azure monitor for all resources in a subscription using Python.
For the same purpose, rest API is available, [check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alertsmanagement/alerts/getall).
I have checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/monitoring?view=azure-python), but it provides the alert / metric definitions and not the alert itself.
Is some thing similar available using Azure python SDK?
Would be helpful if anyone can provide some insights. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is the function that doc provides. But it returns this:
[image]

**It seems not used for the new version.**

[`get_all`](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-mgmt-alertsmanagement/0.2.0rc2/azure.mgmt.alertsmanagement.operations.html#azure.mgmt.alertsmanagement.operations.AlertsOperations.get_all) is used to list all existing alerts. It returns a paging container for iterating over a list of `Alert` object.

Install package: `pip install azure-mgmt-alertsmanagement`

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.alertsmanagement import AlertsManagementClient
 
subscription_id = 'subscription_id '
tenant_id = 'tenant_id '
client_id = 'client_id '
client_secret = 'client_secret'
 
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(tenant=tenant_id, client_id=client_id, secret=client_secret)
 
client = AlertsManagementClient(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)
 
for alert in client.alerts.get_all():
    print((alert.name))
```

---

So, I tried to call the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alertsmanagement/alerts/getall) with Python. It works.

```
import requests
import json

client_id = ''
client_secret = ''
subscription_id = ''
tenant_id = ''

# authorize with azure
url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant_id + "/oauth2/v2.0/token"
data = "scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F.default&client_id=" + client_id + "&grant_type=client_credentials&client_secret=" + client_secret
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)

# create new resource group using Azure REST API
# https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts?api-version=2018-05-05
url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/" + subscription_id + "/providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts?api-version=2018-05-05"
headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + response.json()['access_token']}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.json())
```

[image]